# Shell Script not reading input

Tags: bash, shell, input

I have written a script that backs up and restores files. I have a problem in that when the user enters '2' for a restore the program says that this is an invalid input, all other options work fine. I feel it is something small that I have missed but I cant fix it

**Update and Restore Script**

```
#!/bin/bash

ROOT="/Users/Rory/Documents"
ROOT_EXCLUDE="--exclude=/dev --exclude=/proc --exclude=/sys --exclude=/temp --exclude=/run --exlucde=/mnt --exlcude=/media --exlude=/backup2.tgz"
DESTIN="/Users/Rory/test/"
BACKUP="backup2.tgz"
CREATE="/dev /proc /sys /temp /run /mnt /media "

if [ "$USER" != "root" ]; then
    echo "You are not the root user"
    echo "To use backup please use: sudo backup"
    exit
fi

clear

echo "************************************************"
echo "********* Backup Menu **************************"
echo "************************************************"

OPTIONS="BACKUP RESTORE DESTINATION EXIT"
LIST="1)BACKUP 2)RESTORE 3)DESTINATION 4)EXIT"

select opt in $OPTIONS; do
if [ "$opt" = "EXIT" ]; then
    echo "GOODBYE!"
    sleep 3
    clear
    exit

elif [ "$opt" = "BACKUP" ]; then
    echo "BACKING UP FILES..."
    sleep 2
    tar cvpfz $DESTIN/backup.`date +%d%m%y_%k:%M`.tgz $ROOT $ROOT_EXCLUDE_DIRS
    echo "BACKUP COMPLETE"
    sleep 2
    exit

elif [ "$opt" = "RESTORE" ]; then
    echo "RESTOTING FILES..."
    sleep 2
    tar xvpfz $BACKUP_FILE -C /
    sleep2
    echo "RESTORE COMPLETE..."
    if [[ -e "/proc" ]]; then
            echo "$CREATE_DIRS allready exists! "
    else
            mkdir $CREATE_DIRS
            echo "$CREATE_DIRS are created! "
    fi
    exit
elif [ "$opt" = "DESTINATION" ]; then
    echo "CURRENT DESTINATION: $DEST_DIR/backup.`date +%d/%m/%y_%k:%M`.tgz "
    echo "TO CHANGE ENTER THE NEW DESTINATION..."
    echo "TO LEAVE IT AS IS JUST PRESS ENTER..."
    read NEW_DESTIN

    #IF GREATER THEN 0 ASSIGN NEW DESTINATION
    if [ ${#NEW_DESTIN} -gt 0 ]; then
            DESTIN = "$NEW_DESTIN"
    fi
    clear
    echo $BANNER1
    echo $BANNER2
    echo $BANNER3
    echo $LIST


else
    clear
    echo "BAD INPUT!"
    echo "ENTER 1 , 2, 3 or 4.."
    echo $LIST


fi
done
```

Comment: The code would not get that far. Your `ROOT_EXCLUDE=...` line is missing a terminating double quote. Please ensure that the code you debug and the code you post are exactly the same.

Comment: is `RESTORE` supposed to be a string or a variable? I think it's good practice to prefix variables with a `$`

Comment: Sorry uploaded the wrong code by mistake, fixed the ROOT_EXCLUDE line. @scrowler no it isnt meant to be a string or variable just an option that leads the user to restore the backup

Comment: @Hayes121 so do you expect the user to type in "2" as per your description above or "RESTORE" as the code suggests?

Comment: I ran your code, pressed 2, Enter, and it says "RESTOTING FILES...". Are you getting something else? Can you include the error you're getitng?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except where you missed the ending quote where you set `ROOT_EXCLUDE` (line #4), it looks okay to me. I take it the missing quote is a transcription error or your program wouldn't really work at all.

I've tried out the program and it seems to work.

A debugging trick is to put `set -xv` to turn on debugging in your script and `set +xv` to turn it off. The `-x` means to print out the line before executing, and the `-v` means to print out the line once the shell interpolates the line.

I'm sure that you'll immediately see the issue once you have `set -xv` in your program.

As part of this, you can set `PS4` to the line prompt to print when the debugging information is printed. I like setting PS4 like this:

```
export PS4="[\$LINENO]> "
```

This way, the line prompt prints out the line it's executing which is nice.

In your case, I would put `set -xv` right before you set `OPTIONS` and then at the very end of the program. This way, you can see the `if` comparisons and maybe spot your issue.

```
export PS4="[\$LINENO]> "
set -xv

OPTIONS="BACKUP RESTORE DESTINATION EXIT"
LIST="1)BACKUP 2)RESTORE 3)DESTINATION 4)EXIT"

select opt in $OPTIONS; do
if [ "$opt" = "EXIT" ]; then
    echo "GOODBYE!"
    set +xv
```

---

By the way, it's better to use double square brackets like `[[ ... ]]` for testing rather than the single square brackets like `[ ... ]`. This has to do with the way the shell interpolates the values in the test.

The `[ ... ]` is an alias to the built in `test` command. The shell interpolates the line as is and the entire line is executed.

The `[[ ... ]]` are a compound statement where the shell will interpolate variables, but not the entire line. The line is kept as whole:

```
foo="one thing"
bar="another thing"
```

This will work:

```
if [ "$foo" = "$bar" ]
then
    echo "Foo and bar are the same"
fi
```

This won't:

```
if [ $foo = $bar ]
then
    echo "Foo and bar are the same"
fi
```

The shell interpolates the line as is:

```
if [ one thing = another thing ]
```

And this is the same as:

```
if test one thing = another thing
```

The `test` command looks at the first item to see if it's a standard test, or assumes three items and the second item is a comparison. In this case, neither is true.

However, this will work:

```
if [[ $foo = $bar ]]   # Quotes aren't needed
then
    echo "Foo and bar are the same"
fi
```

With the `[[ ... ]]` being a compound command, the `$foo` and `$bar` are replaced with their values, but their positions are kept. Thus, the `=` is recognized as a comparison operator.

Using `[[ ... ]]` instead of `[ ... ]` has solved a lot of hard to find shell scripting bugs I have.

Comment: I have taken you above advice David and thank you for all the help but I still have the same error that when I press 2 the program tells me it is a bad input. I am running on mac would this make any difference? Also before I added the restore function I just had two option 1)Backup 2)exit, when I pressed 2 to exit the program would do so which has me very confused as to why the 2 isnt working now

Comment: I too have a Mac, and tried your script (at least the part you posted). I modified a few lines to echo the commands  instead of executing them, but I had no problems with selecting option #2. Your script seems just fine. Did you try the `set -xv`? Did you see the output? Is it possible that you're not executing what you think your executing. Try `type <scriptName>` and see where it's executing.